# SmsMessage.isEmail() always returns false

Tags: android, email, sms, telephony

So, in my app, I respond to incoming sms, and I'd like to be able to respond to SMS sent by an email address, but isEmail() always returns false, therefore getEmailFrom() and getEmailBody() always return null. Here's my code:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    String recMsgString = "";            
    String fromAddress = "";
    String tag = "SMS_RECEIVED";

if (bundle != null)
{
    //---retrieve the SMS message received---
   Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

    for (int i=0; i<pdus.length; i++){
        SmsMessage recMsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

        recMsgString = recMsg.getMessageBody();  

        fromAddress = recMsg.getOriginatingAddress();

        if (recMsg.isEmail()){
           fromAddress = recMsg.getEmailFrom();
           recMsgString = recMsg.getEmailBody();
        }

}

       //do some logging
//code to react to the message
       }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda/sorta figured something out, but I'm not sure why it worked...

So, in my app instead of checking `isEmail` and then using `getEmailFrom` and `getEmailBody`, I just got the sender (which is something like 14100000011), and then used `recMsgString.contains(myKeyword)`

My app then sends a message back to 14100000011 and it delivers to my email.

I'm not really sure why it behaves this way, though. I guess AT&Ts email gateway just delivers back to wherever I sent it from. Didn't know this would work.

On a side note, does anyone know the functioning on any other carrier?

That is, if you send an email from gmail (or another email) to your phone number as such:

AT&T: phonenumber@txt.att.net
T-Mobile: phonenumber@tmomail.net
Verizon: phonenumber@vtext.com
Sprint: phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com

Then reply, do you receive a message back in your email?

If anybody is kind enough to test this, please leave a comment saying who your carrier is and who your email provider is and the results of the test.

Answer (score 3):

Hrm well I have never heard of a string method called isEmail() - maybe I am missing something?

You declare

```
String recMsgString = "";
```

and then try to access

```
recMsgString.isEmail()
```

Which does not exist. Also I notice you set recMsgString equal to recMsg.getMessageBody()

```
recMsg.getMessageBody();
```

I wouldn't think the getMessageBody() function would return an email anyway.

I think what you meant to do was:

```
SmsMessage recMsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

        ...

        if (recMsg.isEmail()){
           fromAddress = recMsg.getEmailFrom();
           recMsgString = recMsg.getEmailBody();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I had it correct in my app, but put it in the example code incorrectly. I fixed that now. In the app I use logging to check the value of recMsg.getEmailFrom() and getEmailBody() and isEmail(), and they return null, null, and false, respectively.

Comment: I really don't think there is an answer to my question. I found a solution that works, but it's not what I was wanting. I'm not sure if the problem is a bug in android, or if it's just not really supported as of yet or on all carriers. Thank you for the help, though.